Autocomplete search field that is feed by a taxonomy from custom post type?
So I have a wordpress site that uses Jet Engine filters and I need to build a page that has an autocomplete search that when I start typing for exemple "rep" it shows me "repair", where "repair" is one of the categories from a parent category called "services". Is there a plugin for such a thing? Or something similar?
Tried different plugins but the closest only works with forms or look at post types' titles
